# Non sigma aditivity of the random measures $W$ employed in the construction of the white noise.

Tags: stochastic-analysis, malliavin-calculus

In the page 8 of the book ["The Malliavin Calculus and Related Topics"](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F3-540-28329-3) from Nualart one reads:

[image]

to simplify our ideas, take $\mu$ to be the lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}_+$.

In this case then we can see the white noise as the derivative of the Brownian motion $(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ and define for intervals $[a,b)$:

$$W\big([a,b)\big)= B_b - B_a $$

So for intervals  we have the sigma additivity  ($[a_i,b_i)\cap [a_j, b_j) = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$)
$$\cup_i[a_i,b_i) = [a,b) \Rightarrow W(\cup_i[a_i,b_i)) =  \sum_i B_{b_i} - W_{a_i} = B_b - B_a =W\big([a,b)\big)$$

I imagine it is not the case for arbitrary $\cup_i A_i = A$

That is, one should have $\cup_i A_i = A$, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ for $i \neq j$ and yet

$$W(A) \neq \sum_i W(A_i) $$

Do you have any idea of why is this the case?

Comment: It is always true that $$W(A) = \sum_i W(A_i), \;\;\;\; a.s.$$ for any **deterministic** sequence of disjoint sets $\{A_i\}$. The reason $W$ is not a signed measure is that we would need this to hold simultaneously over **all** such sequences, of which there are uncountably many. And we know that an **uncountable** intersection of events of probability $1$ need not have probability $1$.

Comment: @Shalop , How do we show that finite additivity holds for any pair of measurable sets? Don't we need to hold infinitely many (uncountable) zero measure sets? after all, isn't the Borel sigma algebra uncountable? Or can we use some in some way that the sigma algebra is generated by a denumerable family of subsets?